# Testing image upload and crop using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I am not able to crop the image in selenium ide.
consider the scenario :-

1. After clicking on upload image link one pop up window opens for choose file
2. After choosing the file i got option for upload file
3. after clicking on upload file i got 3 options

   - Crop it
   - Fit to window
   - Cancel

and its mandatory to select any of the three options to upload image to your profile.

I want to automate selenium script for above steps
scripts are recorded properly upto steps 3 but at 4th step selenium is not able record above three options.
( i didn't get any Xpath for above 3 buttons using firebug or xpathfinder addon )

( we are stick to selenium ide 1.10.0 )

Comment: Have you tried using waitForVisible or waitForElementPresent?

Comment: Hi Chim, To use that command i need their id,xpath etc for that button.but i didn't get any thing for  that.But when i automated above with imacros script that thing is recorded an i got embed id="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000",can you please tell me what is it and how can i implement it in selenium ide.